# Can we Converting the xps document to Pdf programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, xps

I am new to the xps documents. I have requirement like convert xps doucment to Pdf format. Can any body have an idea how to do this.

Can u give me any code samples.

Thanks in Advance..

Mehar

Comment: For an open-source solution, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162392/programmatically-print-to-a-pdf-printer). Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ther any open tool to convert XPS to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108319/is-ther-any-open-tool-to-convert-xps-to-pdf)

Comment: Does it answer you question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67146033/9368328

Answer (score 1):

woof woof!

you can use

**ghostpdl**

- http://ghostscript.com/GhostPCL.html

**ghostpdl** is a set of three utilities

```
pcl6
gxps
gsvg
```

to convert the file to **PDF** format. **GhostPDL** can handle *SVG* (and ***XPS*** or *PCL*) in a similar way as Ghostscript does handle PostScript

a sample of how to convert **xps** to **pdf** with gsvg

```
gxps -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=my.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite file.xps
```

Comment: Really underrated answer. This seems to be the most practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but does what you need: [VeryDOC XPS to PDF Converter](http://www.verydoc.com/xps-to-pdf.html)

Another possibility is to convert the XPS document to a Word Doc, and then use a free third party library to convert the Word Doc to PDF (such as [SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/)).

[2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en)