# Convert XPS to PDF in WPF C# application

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, xps

I need to convert an XPS file I create with my application to a PDF file, what is the best way to do so? I prefer this to be done from inside C# using a managed assembly.

Open source is preferred upon third party solutions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ther any open tool to convert XPS to PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108319/is-ther-any-open-tool-to-convert-xps-to-pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the XpsDocument class to read the XPS files, then use a PDF library (such as Report.Net or #PDF) to export it. I used #PDF back in .NET 1.1, but not sure if it can be easily converted to .NET 2.0.

#PDF:
http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/

Report.NET:
http://report.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It seems to have methods to create objects in the PDF no conversion options, how did you intend to convert it

Comment: I think you'll need to convert the XpsDocument to an intermediate format, then convert that to PDF. Also found an interesting project: NDeks Xps (http://www.ndesk.org/Xps).

Answer (score 2):

An open source managed assembly might be hard to find, but you can look at tallcomponents.com for a commercial product that might help, You can have a look at GhostScript.com, its open source and supports both XPS and PDF, although you may have issues redistributing it without a license.

Answer (score 1):

XPS to PDF document conversion using Ghostscript. Please refer below code snippet to convert XPS to PDF

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ghostxps-9.54.0-win32", "gxpswin32.exe");
process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=\"{pdfFilePath}\" -dNOPAUSE \"{xpsFilePath}\"";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Although it is not free, [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html) supports loading XPS files and saving them as PDF.

*Usual disclaimer applies.*